# How to release resources if a program crashes

Tags: c++, c

I have a program that uses services from others. If the program crashes, what is the best way to close those services? At server side, I would define some checkers that monitor if a client is invalid periodically. But can we do any thing at client? I am not the sure if the normal RAII still works at this case. My code is written in C and C++.

Comment: Sorry. My Code uses c and c++. I fixed my question.

Comment: A crash is a crash. Process is gone and there is nothing you can do. Your service connections should be closed by underlying protocol (TCP).

Comment: When a program crashes, the operating system usually releases resources for crashed program.

Comment: depends on what the crash is: if its just an exception, RAII should be enough. If its a segfault, you can register a handler and do cleanup.

Comment: @Bamaco my resource is not aware by OS.

Comment: @JoeC 1. Wouldn't a time-out do the trick in both server and client. 2. What resource, what OS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your application experiences a hard crash, then no, your carefully crafted cleanup code will not run, whether it is part of an RAII paradigm or a method you call at the end of `main`. None of an *application's* cleanup code runs after a crash that causes the application to be terminated.

Of course, this is not true for exceptions. Although those might eventually cause the application to be terminated, they still trigger this termination in a controlled way. Generally, the runtime library will catch an unhandled exception and trigger termination. Along the way, your RAII-based cleanup code will be executed, unless it also throws an exception. Then you're back to being unceremoniously ripped out of memory.

But even if your *application's* cleanup code can't run, the *operating system* will still attempt to clean up after you. This solves the problem of unreleased memory, handles, and other system objects. In general, if you crash, you need not worry about releasing these things. Your application's state is inconsistent, so trying to execute a bunch of cleanup code will just lead to unpredictable and potentially erroneous behavior, not to mention wasting a bunch of time. Just crash and let the system deal with your mess. [As Raymond Chen puts it](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120105-00/?p=8683):

> The building is being demolished. Don't bother sweeping the floor and emptying the trash cans and erasing the whiteboards. And don't line up at the exit to the building so everybody can move their in/out magnet to out. All you're doing is making the demolition team wait for you to finish these pointless housecleaning tasks.

Do what you must; skip everything else.

The only problem with this approach is, as you suggest in this question, when you're managing resources that are not controlled by the operating system, such as a remote resource on another system. In that case, there is very little you can do. The *best* scenario is to make your application as robust as possible so that it doesn't crash, but even that is not a perfect solution. Consider what happens when the power is lost, *e.g.* because a user's cat pulled the cord from the wall. No cleanup code could possibly run then, so even if your application never crashes, there may be termination events that are outside of your control. Therefore, your external resources *must* be robust in the event of failure. Time-outs are a standard method, and a much better solution than polling.

Another possible solution, depending on the particular use case, is to run consistency-checking and cleanup code at application *initialization*. This might be something that you would do for a service that is intended to run continuously and will be restarted promptly after termination. The next time it restarts, it checks its data and/or external resources for consistency, releases and/or re-initializes them as necessary, and then continues on as normal. Obviously this is a bad solution for a typical application, because there is no guarantee that the user will relaunch it in a timely manner.

Answer (score 3):

As the other answers make clear, hoping to clean up after an uncontrolled crash (i.e., a failure which doesn't trigger the C++ exception unwind mechanism) is probably a path to nowhere. Even if you cover some cases, there will be other cases that fail and you are building in a serious vulnerability to those cases.

You mention that the source of the crashes is that you are "us[ing] services from others". I take this to mean that you are running untrusted code in-process, which is the potential source of crashes. In this case, you might consider running the untrusted code "out of process" and communicating back to your main process through a pipe or shared memory or whatever. Then you isolate the crashes this child process, and can do controlled cleanup in your main process. A separate process is really the lightest weight thing you can do that gives you the strong isolation you need to avoid corruption in the calling code.

If forking a process per-call is performance-prohibitive, you can try to keep the child process alive for multiple calls.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be for your program to have two modes: normal operation and monitoring.

When started in a usual way, it would :

1. Act as a background monitor.
2. Launch a subprocess of itself, passing it an internal argument (something that wouldn't clash with normal arguments passed to it, if any).
3. When the subprocess exists, it would release any resources held at the server.

When started with the internal argument, it would:

1. Expose the user interface and "act normally", using the resources of the server.

Answer (score -1):

You might look into [`atexit`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atexit/), which may give you the functionality you need to release resources upon program termination. I don't believe it is infallible, though.

Having said that, however, you should really be focusing on making sure your program doesn't crash; if you're hitting an error that is "unrecoverable", you should still invest in some error-handling code. If the error is caused by a Seg-Fault or some other similar OS-related error, you can either enable SEH exceptions (not sure if this is Windows-specific or not) to enable you to catch them with a normal try-catch block, or write some Signal Handlers to intercept those errors and deal with them.

Comment: `atexit` really isn't a solution, at least not for the question being asked here, since it's only called when the application terminates *normally*, not in the event of a crash. I don't even believe (though I'm not certain) that it would be called by a global unhandled exception handler. Yes, SEH is Windows-specific, and there are certain SEH exceptions that cannot or should not be handled by an application. This gets you into a lot of ugly low-level issues that cannot ever be fully resolved, so you're better off just not trying. An exception handler can't make assumptions about process state.