# How to do some cleaning/closing operations when my application crashes in Qt?

Tags: qt, exception, crash, device

I'm developing an application that uses a device (microprocessor) connected to the pc via USB. I'm using a library with some specific functions for this microprocessor.

At the beginning of the application the user is always required to "login" into the device using a password. What this really do is to execute some initialization functions in the microprocessor, namely:

```
//microprocessor initialization functions
open(); 
device_session = s; // a structure
error=login(&s,password); //if password is ok opens a session 
start();
```

When the user closes the application, I need to also close the device, executing:

```
//microprocessor closing functions
 finish(); 
 logout(&s); // it requires the session structure to close
 close();
```

I do this in the destructor of my application.

The problem is, if my application crashes, the destructor is not executed and the neither are the closing functions. Therefore, the next time I launch the application, the initialization functions fail, as there is another session opened and I can not close it (because logout requires **s**). The only way to make it work again is to reconnect the device to the PC (hardware reset).

So my question is if it is possible to execute the closing functions even when my application crashes, no matter the origin of the error.
I'm trying Overriding QApplication::notify() as described here. Is this the correct approach?
[Qt/C++ Error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661883/qt-c-error-handling)

Another approach I was considering is to have two applications, **A** and **B**.

**A** handles the microprocessor initialization and passes the session object to **B**.

**B** does everything else except closing the microprocessor connection.
When **B** is closed or crashes, **A** simply executes the closing functions. Could this work?

I apologize if the question seems stupid, but I don't have a lot of experience on developing applications. I tried to search for an answer before posting but I'm not sure what approach to follow, so I don't know what should I be searching to begin with.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Generally, crashes and exceptions are two different things. Using multiple processes is a reasonable way to handle the situation, though depending on your operating system there may be others.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to release resources if a program crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40937292/how-to-release-resources-if-a-program-crashes)

Comment: The solution is to create an application that does not crash.  This should be posted as an answer actually.

Comment: AFAIK, the only effective strategy to contain crashes and possibly recover from them is to design your application around a process guard.  Essentially you init your application in a parent process, and if the init procedure is successful then you launch the remaining components as a child process.  If the child process crashes you can either try to recover from those crashes or simply call your cleanup procedures.  Yet, process guards don't fix bad code, and if your app is crashing that frequently then you should focus on actually fixing the problems that cause the crash.